# "LinkedList is not generic" error Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, linked-list

I'm getting an error when trying to create the linked list that says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>   
> The type LinkedList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>
>   
> at LinkedList.main(LinkedList.java:7)

Anyone know how to fix this error? Here is the program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many elements do you want to add: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print("Add Element: ");
            String element = input.next();
            list.add(element);
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("LinkedList elements are: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The LinkedList class that you are creating is a Java built class library in Collections. Change your classname.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change

```
new LinkedList<String>()
```

to

```
new java.util.LinkedList<String>()
```

The source of the problem is that `LinkedList` refers to the class containing the code `class LinkedList`, not `java.util.LinkedList`.

Unqualified class names like `LinkedList` (in contrast to "fully-qualified names" like `java.util.LinkedList`) are resolved by looking for a match in a certain order.  Roughly

1. Look for a containing class.
2. Look for a non-wildcard import.
3. Look for a class in the same package.
4. Look for a wildcard import.

Section ["6.5 Determining the Meaning of a Name"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html#6.5) of the Java language specification explains in more detail.

Comment: I'd bet a lot that you were using Eclipse.... Eclipse loves to refer to the strangest libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Your class is also called LinkedList so it conflicts. If you want to fix it use this line instead. Better still, just have a different name for your class...

```
List<String> list = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class LinkedList {
```

Your class is not defined as generic.  I think though that you are trying to use Java's LinkedList, so you should rename your class.

Answer (score 2):

You placed your `main` method in a class called `LinkedList`, which takes precedence over the built-in `LinkedList` class in the compiler's name resolution algorithm.  In other words, because your `main` method is inside a class called `LinkedList`, the compiler takes the name `LinkedList` to mean *your* `LinkedList` class instead of `java.util.LinkedList`.  There are two easy fixes:

1. Rename your class
2. Instead of writing

   List list = new LinkedList();

   write

   List list = new java.util.LinkedList();

I highly recommend the first option.  Since your `LinkedList` class doesn't actually represent the linked list data structure, the name on your class is confusing to someone reading the code.  Maybe call your class `LinkedListTest` instead i.e. your file could be

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedListTest {
    // Implementation of main and helper methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class LinkedList {
```

You named your own class `LinkedList`, so it's taking precedence over the `java.util.LinkedList`.

Either change the name of the class to something else or do `new java.util.LinkedList<String>()` to make it explicit which one you want.